# How to find the max number in this type of data structure in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Im not entirely sure what the name of this type of data structure (a table??),

```
T = [[(0, ''), (-1, '<'), (-2, '<')], [(-1, '^'), (1, '\\'), (0, '\\')], [(-2, '^'), (5, '^'), (0, '\\')]]
```

Anyway, we're using it in college for a certain type of program, but that doesn't really matter, basically I have a very complex program already done which use's this type of data structure, however now I need to write another program that does something very similar, basically it would save me a great deal of work if there was a way to get the maximum number from this list of tuples, in a list of lists, along with the index of that value. Also the number of tuples, or lists is not fixed, that will change depending on the length of a string put into the program. It also important to note **I am not just looking for the maximum number, but also the index of that number**.
With this type of data structure,

```
T[2][2][1]
```

would return

```
'\ \'
```

In the example I gave above I would be looking for

```
T[2][1][0]
```

which would return

```
5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like the dynamic algorithm for the longest common subsequence problem :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't even realise what that tick meant under the question, I went back and accepted the ones that worked! And ya its the longest common subsequence alright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pretty concise method:

```
max((k, (i, j)) for i, lst in enumerate(T) for j, (k, _) in enumerate(lst))
```

For your sample data:

```
>>> T = [[(0, ''), (-1, '<'), (-2, '<')], [(-1, '^'), (1, '\\'), (0, '\\')], [(-2, '^'), (5, '^'), (0, '\\')]]
>>> max((k, (i, j)) for i, lst in enumerate(T) for j, (k, _) in enumerate(lst))
(5, (2, 1))
>>> T[2][1]
(5, '^')
```

Comment: Your pretty damn awesome at python, is this a tuple comprehension?

Comment: Glad it helped!  This is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) wrapped in the [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

Good old way?

```
def find_max(table):
    max_val = table[0][0][0] # something to start with
    max_index = (0, 0)
    for l in table:
        for t in l:
            if t[0] > max_val:
                max_val = t[0]
                max_index = (table.index(l), l.index(t))
    return (max_val, max_index)
```

Comment: I didn't realise there was a good old way! I'll try this out, thanks.

Comment: `l` and `t` are not integers, and even if they were could not be used correctly for indexes.

Comment: And again. Sorry, I should have tested it first.

Answer (score 0):

Homework, eh?  Here's some clues:

- iterate through the list, and the list, and compare the 0th values
- [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) is you friend

Not homework?  OKay, here's a solution  :)

```
high = 0
index = None
for i, lst in enumerate(T):
    for j, tpl in enumerate(lst):
        current = T[i][j][0]
        if current > high:
            index = i, j, 0
        high = max(high, current)

print index
```

Comment: haha, its not homeword, its part of a research project, we're mainly focused on biology here so we're not so great with the computer science, but thanks for the advise

Answer (score -1):

```
T=[[(0, ''), (-1, '<'), (-2, '<')], [(-1, '^'), (1, '\\'), (0, '\\')], [(-2, '^'), (5, '^'), (0, '\\')]]

m, ma, mb=None, 0, 0
for a in xrange(len(T)):
        for b in xrange(len(T[a])):
                if m is None or T[a][b] > m:
                        m, ma, mb=T[a][b], a, b

print m, ma, mb
```

This will print

```
(5, '^') 2 1
```